# Can one train estimators in a scikit-learn pipeline simultaneously?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn, pipeline

Is it possible to do the following in scikit-learn? We train an estimator A using the given mapping from features to targets, then we use the same data (or mapping) to train another estimator B, then we use outputs of the two trained estimators (A and B) as inputs for an estimator C and as the target we use the same target as before.

In other words, we train two estimators (predictors) and then we try to combine the "weak" predictions coming from the estimator A and B to get a better ("stronger") prediction. To find the best way to combine the two types of predictions (from estimator A and B) we use another training (in fact we learn in an automatic way how to combine the given predictions).

So, we have the following structure:

```
A -> C
B -> C
```

Now, I want to have the same "tree" of estimators. However, I want to train them simultaneously. By that I mean that expertises of the estimator A and B should not be evaluated by their ability to predict the target. I want instead to evaluate the expertises of these two estimators by their ability to improve the predictions coming from the estimator C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own transformer that'll `transform` input into predictions. Something like this:

```
class PredictionTransformer(sklearn.base.BaseEstimator, sklearn.base.TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, estimator):
        self.estimator = estimator

    def fit(self, X, y):
        self.estimator.fit(X, y)
        return self

    def transform(self, X): 
        return self.estimator.predict_proba(X)
```

Then you can use [`FeatureUnion`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html) to glue your transformers together.

That said, there's a caveat: this technique is known as [Stacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning#Stacking) and is prone to overfitting when all classifiers are trained using the same data, so you might want to write something more sophisticated that will partition train set into 2 parts: one to fit base predictors, and one to fit meta learner (the one that combines base predictions).

Comment: if I understood the "stacking" correctly, it is not what I need. In the stacking we first train the "weak" estimators using the data, and then we train another "strong" estimator, that learns how to use the outputs of the "weak" estimators in the best way. What I need, is a simultaneous training of the estimators (not subsequent). Which means that "weak" estimators are not trained with the real target. Instead the "weak" estimators have to be evaluated on their ability to  provide a useful input for the "strong" estimator (and NOT on their ability to predict the real target).

Comment: it also looks like (maybe I am wrong) that `FeatureUnion` is not what I am searching for. In the examples that I saw, the `FeatureUnion` have been use to combine transformers and I need to combine predictors.

Comment: @Roman, that's what the first part of my answer is about. You can write a simple wrapper that will make a transformer out of your predictor.